# How to keep unique items from a collection of similar items in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list like the following

```
a = [5,5,5,5,3,3,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,2,2,2,2,2]
```

I wish to have the following output list

```
b = [5,3,2,5,2]
```

Note that I have tried using

```
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(a))
```

which gives me

```
[5, 3, 2]
```

Notice that it does not consider the 2nd 5 or the 2nd 2 as they are non-unique by then.

I need a way to make the machine understand that as and when it encounters a unique element (say the first '5'), it should store it in list b. Consequently, when it encounters the first '3' or first '2', it should store them in list b as well. No problems until this point. As it encounters the second set of '5's, it should store that 5 as a new element in list b. Same goes for the second set of 2's.

Is there a Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than just doing a for loop you could use itertools groupby:

```
import itertools

a = [5,5,5,5,3,3,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,2,2,2,2,2]
b = [x[0] for x in itertools.groupby(a)]  # [5, 3, 2, 5, 2]
```

Documentation for this can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

EDIT: Some clarification. The reason this is able to count re-occurrences in the list is explained by this paragraph in the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The operation of groupby() is similar to the uniq filter in Unix. It
>   generates a break or **new group every time the value of the key
>   function changes** [...]

Answer (score 0):

Bro u solve this problem without any iterator using list comprehensive

```
a = [5,5,5,5,3,3,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,2,2,2,2,2]
b = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i]! = a[i-1]]
Print(b)
Output is b = [5,3,2,5,2]
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the case where the last digit is the same as the first.